# Incremental Publishing in Eclipse for Static Web Project

Tags: eclipse, publishing

I have a static Web project added to an Apache server. Whenever I make a change to the project, regardless of how small the change is, the entire project republishes instead of the individual file. I was under the impression that the publishing process was supposed to keep a delta and only republish the files that have been marked as changed in the delta.

I wouldn't mind if the project were small, but it's a large project (200+ MB) and the connection to the server I'm publishing to is a bit slow. A republish takes anywhere between 15 minutes and a half hour.

Does anybody know if my install of Eclipse is working as expected?

---

**Environment Specifics:**

- Eclipse Galileo
- Aptana Studio Plug-in 1.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you've found a bug. Try rsync instead.

There was a [bug about delta publishing](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206087), but it should be fixed by now. And from other Eclipse projects, I assume that they added a test case for this, so it shouldn't happen again. But maybe your circumstances trigger a new bug.

Are you manually changing the files or do you use some script outside of Eclipse? Anything that makes Eclipse think the whole project has changed, will trigger a full redeploy.

Comment: According to the thread at http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg14916.html it seems like incremental publishing is supposed to work. Either I'm not doing something right, or a bug is getting in my way.

Comment: I'd think that they added a test case for this since the bug ought to be fixed.